# Ranking Arrays based on an specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays of users points like this:

```
let groupRank = [];

userA = ["Sara", "24"];
userB = ["John", "12"];
userC = ["Eddi", "20"];
userD = ["Marry", "13"];
```

and I want to rank them based on their points and get this:

```
Console.log(groupRank);
//Sara, Eddi, Marry, John
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a 2D array and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it based on the `points` which is at index `1`. Then use to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the names which are at index `0`

```js
let array = [
  ["Sara", "24"],
  ["John", "12"],
  ["Eddi", "20"],
  ["Marry", "13"]
]

const sortedNames = array.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
                         .map(a => a[0])

console.log(sortedNames.join())
```

If you have all those arrays in separate variables, you can create the 2D array like this:

```
let array = [ userA, userB, userC, userD ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First group all array in one array.
2. Then apply sorting based one `1` index
3. create the array only with name using **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
let groupRank = [];

userA = ["Sara", "24"];
userB = ["John", "12"];
userC = ["Eddi", "20"];
userD = ["Marry", "13"];
var res = [userA,userB,userC,userD]; //group all in one
res = res.sort((a,b)=> b[1]-a[1]); // sort based on point
res = res.map(a=> a[0]); //map the names only
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` function and put all the users inside an array. Then use sort function and while sorting convert the pointer to a number using unary operator. `sort` will give an array of arrays. If you need the name then use `map` function to get the array of name

```js
let groupRank = [];

let userA = ["Sara", "24"];
let userB = ["John", "12"];
let userC = ["Eddi", "20"];
let userD = ["Marry", "13"];

let allUsers = [userA, userB, userC, userD];

groupRank = allUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +b[1] - (+a[1])
}).map(item => item[0])


console.log(groupRank)
```